# What's the C# equivalent to Pascal's: Integer, Longword, and Extended?

Tags: c#, pascal

I'm trying to convert Pascal code to C# code.

What's the C# equivalent to Pascal's: Integer, Longword, and Extended?

Comment: This isn't a good question for StackOverflow. Just use Google, check C# and Pascal types and find out the equivalences yourself....

Comment: You need to be more specific. What Pascal are you using? C# has precise definitions for each data type, but Pascal does not. "Integer" means different things in different Pascal implementations, and "Longword" and "Extended" aren't even part of the basic Pascal language. If you are porting Pascal to C#, I recommend that instead of hoping for a one-to-one translation key, you do enough research that you understand the source code's _purpose_ and _intent_, and then learn C# well enough to write a C# program with the same purpose and intent.

Comment: `Longword` is specific to Delphi and FreePascal. So `Integer` maps to `int`, `Longword` maps to `uint` and `Extended` to whatever the C# mapping is for the 80bit FPU type (if any) in Win32 and to `double` in Win64.

Comment: Afaik longword was originally a winapi alias for (32-bit) uint, and not really a Pascal type.  The later introduced CARDINAL is the real language designation. (as per e.g. M2). Nowadays I would translate it as uint32

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: although this has been muddied a little lately, Integer and Cardinal were the signed and unsigned (respectively) so called "generic" integral types, while Byte, Shortint, Word, Smallint, Longword and Longint were so called fixed size types. Integer currently maps to Longint and Cardinal to Longword. To avoid the recent changes, for fixed size, I currently use Int8, Uint8 ... Int64, UInt64, which are defined too, these days.

Comment: That's what I meant.. Same with Pascal successors, except that e.g. in Modula2 CARDINAL is the main type.  The fixed types are added in iirc XE2, FPC added them in 2.4.2, but had the same prefixed with "C" (so cint8 etc) since +/- 2005 in unit "ctypes".to avoid repeated definitions in API units.

Answer (score 1):

Pascal `Integer` => `int` in C#

`Longword` => `uint`

`Extended` => no exact match, closest is `double`.

Comment: Cardinal is general purpose uint, not longword, longword is a winapi type See comments question

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort: Longword is not a "winapi type". It is just as much a language type as Byte or Int64. Winapi types are DWORD or WPARAM, etc.